# Android Save and Restore List State with CursorAdapter

Tags: android, save, restore, simplecursoradapter, android-cursoradapter

I have a list view in a fragment that is populated by a CursorAdapter.

When the device rotates I want to save the state of the list, then restore it without having to make another call to the SQLite DB.

How do I do this?

I'm not using a ContentProvider or any CursorLoaders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could save your `Cursor` in the method [onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRetainNonConfigurationInstance%28%29) of your Activity or use a data fragment that holds the Cursor and call [setReatinInstance()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance%28boolean%29) within the fragment's `onCreate()` method.

You then have to recreate the `CursorAdapter` within the `onCreate()` method.

Finally you have to store the currently visible topmost item of your `ListView` by calling [getFirstVisiblePosition()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getFirstVisiblePosition%28%29) on your `ListView`. This method returns an int value which you can store in a `Bundle` within the `onSaveInstanceState()` method of your Activity.

You use this value in the `onCreate()` method (it's part of the bundle passed to onCreate()). And after the adapter has been set, you call [setSelectionFromTop(yourValue, 0)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setSelectionFromTop(int, int)).

Comment: I am using a fragment and setRetainInstace(true) was all I needed. Thank you for providing details on both solutions!